# How to parse the text returned by servlet to a $.post() request in Javascript

Tags: javascript, ajax, jsp, jquery

My java script is like this:

```
$.post("url", {
        x: y,
        a: b
    },

    function (data) {
        if (data == "success") {
            $("#results").html("success");
            updatefunction(); // Need to update some values in database
        } else {
            $("#results").html("transaction failed: " + data);
        }
    });
```

And My servlet returns this:

```
PrintWriter out = response.getWriter();
if(balance == true){
   out.println("success");
}
else{
    out.println("In Sufficient Balance");
}
```

I cannot compare the string returned by my servlet back in the javascript. I don't want to use JSON or XML and make the program complex.

Is there anywhere that I can parse that (data) to a string so that basing on success I can do the remaining....

Every time it goes into else loop and update by #results with:  transaction failed: success

Comment: did you actually debug and see what the data is. I am betting you have whitespace. Is it really hard to output a JSON object? It is not rocket science.

Comment: println will also append the whitespace at the end ... also check the setContentType is text and not html ... finally change it to JSON if you can ... will make things easy later on

Comment: are you sure this is valid? the syntax is wrong, and "url" does not do anything

Comment: No, my #results <div> is updated: success on my web page. Well the returned data is only one string, so I was looking for a simpler way to parse it.

Comment: it's probably whitespace.. you could try jQuery.trim(data) == 'success'

Comment: jQuery.trim() worked. Thanks a ton @joseph caracuel

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I used jQuery.trim(string) to remove the white space from the string. Also made changes to the content type in my servlet to:

```
response.setcontenttype("text");
```

Thanks to @jsshah and @joseph caracuel

Answer (score 0):

It is most likely white space.  Just check for the instance of the string.

```
if(data.indexOf("success") !== -1){
  ...
```

Answer (score 0):

trace the response from the servlet,like this

```
$.post("url", 
{x:y, a:b}, 
function(data){
   alert(data);
   if(data == "success"){
        $("#results").html("success");
        updatefunction();   // Need to update some values in database
    }
    else{
        $("#results").html("transaction failed: "+ data);
    }
});
```

Comment: Program is working perfectly fine. Except for the if statement. I can see the data returned is "success" my updating my div before the if statement or alert as you wrote.

Comment: That's strange,maybe there are some whitespaces like the others said